# How to build okhttp.jar from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/

Tags: android, okhttp

I cloned: [okhttp source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/).
How do I build `okhttp.jar` for `Android`?
maven, ndk-build, other?
maven gives errors. ndk-build looks for jni dir and needs Application.mk
Please explain.
KB

Comment: Do you want to build AOSP's fork, or do you want to build the current version of OkHttp off master?

Comment: I don't understand the question! But let's say the current version of OkHttp off master. I spent a lot of time yesterday trying to frig the AOSP build system without downloading the whole of it! But this was frustratingly difficult (on x86!). I ONLY want my own version of okhttp.jar.

Comment: Clone GitHub.com/square/okhttp and import the project into IntelliJ.

Comment: see https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2201 - JakeWharton commented on 6 Jan 2016. I need to use  jarjar rules

Comment: What do you want to do with the okhttp.jar once you build it?

Comment: There is an android app called "Words with Friends". I want to add log output to okhttp.jar to see its http traffic. I tried using Fiddler, but the app refuses to run with a proxy configured.

Comment: Use Charles proxy? Otherwise, you are going to have to compile AOSP from source. It's not trivial to get set up, and that's a different topic haha.

Comment: Haha indeed! LOL. I discovered that yesterday! Charles proxy? Won't it be the same problem as Fiddler (see above) "Words with Friends" already uses a proxy I think. Currently trying to compile Wireshark on Linux. Hope this will do the job!